# Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test vs ANOVA for comparison of variable across multiple groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

When comparing a non-normally distributed variable across multiple groups, is it okay to use a Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test or is it necessary to use (non-parametric) ANOVA?

The `ggsignif` package makes it easy indicate significant differences in plots (generated with the very helpful `ggplot2` library.

However, looking at the examples shown on the GitHub repository of the `ggsignif` package (https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif), I'm wondering whether it would be better to use ANOVA in most of the examples.

The examples on https://statisticsglobe.com/ggsignif-package-r also use t-tests across more groups.

On the other hand, http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/ uses the `ggpubr` package and Kruskal-Wallis tests when comparing a variable across more than one group.

Comment: Wilcoxon's test compares two groups, so the question is a bit hard to understand. Its extension to more than two groups is the Kruskal-Wallis test, a rank-based ANOVA.

Comment: In case you want to compare a non-normally distributed variable across three groups, you could also compare each pair of groups with a Wilcoxon test.

Comment: Agreed. But that will need correction for multiple testing, depending on the exact research question(s).